# Android XML Parsing using SAX Parser 2

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am trying to simply xml parsing using SAX parser.When i do Run it did not show result.I have given xml file into assets folder.But why it is not work I can not understand.Please help me.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.backgroud_ahsanul;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView txt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser=factory.newSAXParser();
            DefaultHandler handler=new DefaultHandler(){
            boolean name=false;
            boolean salary=false;

            public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                    String qName, org.xml.sax.Attributes attributes) throws org.xml.sax.SAXException {
                if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
                    name=true;
                }
               if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("salary")){
                   salary=true;
               }

            }

            public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws org.xml.sax.SAXException {



            }

            @Override
                public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                        throws SAXException {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.characters(ch, start, length);
                    if(name){
                        txt.setText(txt.getText()+"\n\n Name: "+new String(ch,start,length));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        name=false;
                    }
                    if(salary){
                        txt.setText(txt.getText()+"\n\n Salary: "+new String(ch,start,length));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "salary", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        salary=false;
                    }

                }


            };

            InputStream is=getAssets().open("file.xml");
            saxParser.parse(is, handler);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


}
```

**layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="76dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

IF you want to see my document file you get this link:
http://codepad.org/SAnFP1hr

Comment: Looking at your xml file and the error, you shouldn't have this line in the file: File: file.xml  It doesn't understand the colon.

Comment: oh sorry it is mistack , i Edit this @garret Moore

Comment: What error are you getting when you run the program?  Paste your logcat.

Comment: it is my post problem it is not coding problem bro @GarretMoore

Comment: As I understand it:  There are no errors when you run the program.  It just doesn't parse the xml.  Am I correct?

Comment: yah bro...r8 @GarretMoore

Comment: Give me a few mins, I'm importing your code.

Comment: I can send this zip Code in your Email.please give me Email @GarretMoore

Comment: I downloaded your code and it works.  It displays an activity that shows the name and salary of the three guys listed in file.xml.

Comment: ohh realy ... please tell me what problem my code?

Comment: Are you using an emulator, or an actual phone?  What exactly happens after you run?

Comment: I use Emulator, it show normaly TextView not another ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! The XML parser hates white space before the first tag.

Open file.xml and delete the white space before the first tag.

The XML you provided omitted that and that's why it worked for me!

Comment: It only showed me the text view "Large Text" after I removed file.xml from the assets folder.  So for some reason, it's not reading that file for you.

Comment: hmm... look in your layout folder, is activity_main.xml in there and populated with what you provided above?